# multi level dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i've been trying to figure out how to make a foreach loop on a multi-dimesial array but sadly with no luck, i have the below array

```
$levels = [
        'A' => [
            'xx' => null,
            'yy' => 0
        ],
        'B' => [
            'xx' => 1,
            'yy' => 100
        ],
        'C' => [
            'xx' => 3,
            'yy' => 250
        ],
        'D' => [
            'xx' => 6,
            'yy' => 500
        ]
    ];
```

the `xx` & `yy` are columns in a table and am simply trying to assign some values to both of them like so

```
foreach ($levels as $level => $info) {
    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        Level::create([
             'name' => $level,
             'xx'   => $value,
             'yy'   => $value
         ]);
      }
  }
```

but this doesnt work and it creates a duplicated entries :(.

Comment: The part of code you showed seems quite correct. The problem must be in your `create()` method, so please show it.

Comment: actually you don't need another depth of `foreach`, in the first foreach just use `$info['xx']` and `$info['yy']`

Comment: @Ghost r u kidding me, its that easy O.o, many many thanx for your quick response :)

Comment: @ctf0 yes that's why you got the duplicates, you're looping under the unneeded depth, the first `foreach` is just all you need, glad this helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the inner foreach. You can reach xx, yy from $info:

```
foreach ($levels as $level => $info) {
    Level::create([
         'name' => $level,
         'xx'   => $info['xx'],
         'yy'   => $info['yy']
     ]);
}
```